# "arch already exists in fat dylib" in build log

Tags: ios, xcodebuild

This line repeats many times in my build logs of my iOS project (its built by jenkins).

> arch already exists in fat dylib

Is it something to worry about? It builds fine, but its a little hard to read the build logs with that being repeated hundreds of times.

I am using ARC and iOS 7.

I do not have any more information to provide, as I do not know anything about the problem, and any search for the message leads me to this question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is does not provide enough information about the issue seen 

Comment: @Mark How can I provide any more information? This appears for every file in my project, and I'm not posting my whole project.

Comment: Do you have the same errors in Xcode, what are the link lines etc see  SSCCE.org for some idea what to do/ What versions of Xcode and the OS,. Can you reduce the project to a simpleHello World and still get the error or what bit of code when you remove it removes the error