# App Code arch already exists in fat dylib

Tags: ios, appcode

I am getting the following error `arch already exists in fat dylib` a good number of times when trying to build my project in app code. The project was running fine then out of the blue this error came up.

I am running App Code version 2.5.4.

I have tried restarting App Code, cleaning and rebuilding, and a numerous amount of other things.

I saw the thread on this ["arch already exists in fat dylib" in build log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392902/arch-already-exists-in-fat-dylib-in-build-log) but when I cannot find the Developer folder it speaks of, and believe it has been removed in newer versions of app code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out after a couple hours of fiddling that this was caused when Xcode auto-updated to 5.1. To relieve this error I simply had to restart my computer, open the project in Xcode and compile it, then return to App Code and the errors disappeared.

Hope this will save someone the hassel of figuring out the issue and solution.

Comment: you should update to AppCode 2.5.5. anyways (better support for Xcode 5.1)

Comment: I had given that a try at a certain point, and it still was throwing the errors until I ran the project in Xcode. Although I do agree that it should be updated.

Comment: I just had this happen in AppCode 3.0. Simply opening the project in XCode and building it there once fixed the problem, no restarts necessary.

Comment: @aranasaurus Hmm maybe because i had already had the project open in XCode and appcode that did not work. I had tried building it in XCode and it still failed. Either way good to now